# Why does std::is_assignable return false with related pointer types?

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits

Given two very simple classes:

```
class X
{
};

class Y : public X
{
};
```

Why is it that, with Clang and [GCC targeting C++14](https://ideone.com/fdIuVC), `std::is_assignable<X*, Y*>::value` is `false`? It is `true` with Clang on my setup when I target C++11.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because in your case `X*` becomes an rvalue. You can't assign to an rvalue. Change to an lvalue instead:

```
std::is_assignable<X*&, Y*>::value
//                  ~^~
```

Answer (score 25):

[`std::is_assignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable) checks:

> If the expression `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` is well-formed in unevaluated context

But you can't assign *to* an rvalue (which is what `declval<X*>()` would be) at all. You need an *lvalue* on the left-hand side of the assignment:

```
std::is_assignable<X*&, Y*>::value
```

That would be true. If Clang is returning true, that's definitely a Clang bug.